# Capacitors to smooth output of cheap variable PSU

Tags: power-supply, capacitor

I've got a cheap variable PSU (Eventek 0-10A 0-30V) and I'm curious about building something to smooth the output voltage from it. *I don't need to do this, the PSU is working fine for my needs right now, but I think it is an interesting problem to work through.*

The [specs on the PSU](https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/B1OyuYQCw9S.pdf) say the regulation is `≤1mV in CV mode ≤3mA in CC mode`. But the manual says `Ripple voltage: Vpp≤1%`. So at worst 0.3V? I'll check that with an oscilloscope before buying anything.

Can I just put a capacitor or two in parallel with the output? I'd just put them in a project box with binding posts on both sides. Do I need to worry about ESR capacitors? Do I need to worry about the capacitors feeding power back into the PSU? If so, why? It feels like any DC load with a capacitor on it's input would have the same problem.

Thanks for any advice and help sizing this.

Comment: What problems do you think the ripple will cause you? What frequency will the ripple be? Do you really need to do this?

Comment: You can’t simply lump a cap in parallel. You must examine the load impedance (dynamic) and source spectrum for ripple then choose the ripple filter spec you need and design the impedances accordingly. This is a result of load regulation.

Comment: I tried to head this off in the question with: "I don't need this.. it is working fine for my needs right now, but I think it is an interesting problem to work through." I bought a cheap PSU for home projects and as far as I know, it isn't causing problems for my needs. 

This is really just an excuse to work thru the problem, based on what I think I know about capacitors, testing before and after with an oscilloscope. I've use capacitors before in R/C aircraft to help with temporary voltage sags, and it got me thinking I could use them for this.

Comment: If they could have improved this easily , they would have. Consider phase margin , overshoot, load regulation and ripple

Comment: Add a link to the data sheet of the supply.

Comment: @Andyaka: Added the PDF manual, it's all I found.

Comment: It doesn't really say anything new (pity). I was looking for a statement that might indicate what frequency the ripple is. Then. you could design an RLC low pass filter that should improve the ripple p-p. Adding capacitors is unlikely to make significant in roads and might, in some cases, make things worse.

Comment: Ok, thanks to all for the comments. Reading: "this probably won't do what you want" is a result, even though I don't get to build anything.

Comment: IMO, worth doing just for the experience, but what will eventually happen will be probably buying a linear supply from ebay

Comment: @Transistor: I forgot you asked this, and I had an oscope out today so I attempted to measure this PSU with just a 20Ohm resistor as the load. I measured at 20V 1A, and 12V 0.6A.  Ripple frequency is about 6.8Mhz and peak-to-peak is about 120mV